# Filter Scala dataframe by column of arrays

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

My scala dataframe has a column that has the datatype `array`(`element: String`). I want to display those rows of the dataframe that has the word "hello" in that column.

I have this:

```
display(df.filter($"my_column".contains("hello")))
```

I get an error because of data mismatch. It says that `argument 1 requires string type, however, '`my:column`' is of array<string> type`.

Comment: try `array_contains` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_contains` function

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.filter(array_contains(df.col("my_column"), "hello")).show
```